# Clang and the 'override' keyword in derived template classes

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, overriding, clang

I have a class tree of three classes like this:

```
class A {
    public:
    virtual void function() = 0;
};

template<typename type> class B : public A {
};

template<typename type> class C : public B<type> {
    void function() override {
    }
};
```

I use the `override` keyword in `C` to make the compiler issue an error if I get the definition wrong. When compiling with `GCC`, I don't get any error and the program compiles. I assume this is correct behavior since `function()` is defined virtual in the base class `A`.

If I compile it with `clang` however, it doesn't find the function in `A`, and issues an compiler error with nice colors:

```
test.cpp:10:2: error: only virtual member functions can be marked 'override'
        void function() override {
```

Is this a bug in `clang`, or is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: Which version of `clang`?

Comment: Sry, heres the whole thing: `Debian clang version 3.0-6.2 (tags/RELEASE_30/final) (based on LLVM 3.0)`

Comment: yeah, this isn't an issue on my chain: `clang-500.2.79 (based on LLVM 3.3svn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct to me, and:

- It succeeds with gcc 4.8.1.
- It fails with clang 3.1.
- It *succeeds* with clang 3.2.

I think that answers the question. (Tested on RHEL 5.4).

Edit: Looks like it may be [this issue](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13499) (not identical, but closest I found).

Comment: Yea, I can't compile the code from the bug report either. Cheers.